# ReqEx expression for form validation

Tags: regex, xss

I am trying to add form validation to my html site in order to prevent xss injection attacks.

I am using a simple java form validator genvalidator_v4.js that allows me to use regex expressions to determine what is allowed in a text box. I am trying to write one that would prevent "<" or ">" or any other tags that could be used in this kind of attack, but still allow alphanumeric, punctuation, and other special characters.

Any ideas? Also open to other methods of preventing xss attacks but I am very inexperienced in this area so please keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: genvalidator_v4 **.js** does not seem to be written in Java, is it?

Comment: You can't expect client-side validations to prevent XSS attacks.  You need to use server-side code, perhaps *in conjunction* with client-side validation.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to **blacklist** dangerous input. That's very tricky, it's very easy to get it wrong because of the sheer number of tokens that *could* be dangerous.

Thus, the following two practices are recommended instead:

- **Escape** everything read from the database **before outputting** it on a web page. If you correctly HtmlEncode everything (your language of choice surely has a library method for that), it *doesn't matter* if a user entered `<script>/* do something evil */</script>` and that code got stored in your database. Correctly encoded, this will just be printed verbatim and do no harm.
- If you still want to filter *input* (which might be useful as an *additional* layer of security), **whitelists** are generally safer than blacklists. So, instead of saying that `<` is harmful, you say that letters, digits, punctuation, etc. are safe. What exactly is safe depends on what type of field you are filtering.

Comment: Okay I would like to go with your first method, but I am not able to find any guides for telling me how to do this. I don't have a DB per say because my site is just simple html pages, one of which has the form in question on it. How would I go about implementing your first method on a simple site like this? I just want my site to not be vulnerable to cross site scripting attacks so any solution with this effect would suffice.

Comment: What do you do with the form data?

Comment: <FORM ACTION = "https://www.MyWebSite.com/cgi-bin/cgiemail/mailform.txt" METHOD = "post" id="myform">

Comment: this results in an email being sent with the order information

Comment: An XSS attack works as follows: The attacker makes sure you put *his* script data on *your* webpage. Usually this works by the attacker entering the script in some web form and the web application printing this data unescaped on a web page. Since your application never shows any data input by the user on a web page, I cannot see how XSS can happen here at all.

Comment: The problem is that the form is used to transmit credit card info, & due to this vulnerability it is failing PCI compliance.

Comment: @Josh: I still don't see the vulnerability. Please explain: How could someone do a successful XSS attack on your site?

Comment: They can't. I understand that I do not have the vulnerability, but the problem is that I am failing the SecuritMetrics PCI compliance scan which credit card processor requires me to pass. You can't argue with city hall.  I have the results of the scan but I'm unable to include them here, do you have an email address i could send them to?

Comment: The Security Metrics tech told me that I had to Sanitize my HTML on the Form. I did as much research as I could & determined that I had to prevent scripts from being executed on my form, which is probably what they are getting the form to do, & thus they are failing me. I fully realize that I am not at risk, but they are not willing to look at my site specifically. THey simply run the scan & if you fail, you are toast. I tried to include the scan results here, but I am being prevented from including the results due to some function of the system we are conversing on.

Comment: @Josh: I see. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with SecurityMetrics, so I'm afraid I won't be able to help here. As Inuyasha correctly says, client-side validation is irrelevant from a security point of view, you'll have to modify your mailform cgi to include some kind of validation.

Comment: I have used HTMLPurifier to eliminate      <>)( %& -+";             from being input, as these are what I have learned are what can be used to try to run scripts on my form. I still need to figure out how to Sanitize my HTML on the Server side. I have determined that the method of doing so, is dependent upon the language being used on the server, but that is beyond my scope of undestanding. The site's form is www.tennismenace.com/mailform.html

Comment: Do you have any required fields and then do a page load with old data requiring the missing data to be filled in if any of them are missing?

Comment: Btw javascript validation in the browser has nothing to do with security, because an attacker can simply disable it. It's for usability.